# How to make button widget display text and colour once pressed

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget

So I have a button widget and I want it to display the text and colour of the widget once clicked. I can't use the `.cget` method to do this as there are multiple buttons of the same name created in a loop so it will just give the text and colour of the last created button widget. Trying not use complicated methods & make it as simple as possible.

```
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(10):

        if x == 0:
            x_row = 'A'
        elif x == 1:
            x_row = 'B'
        elif x == 2:
            x_row = 'C'
        elif x == 3:
            x_row = 'D'
        elif x == 4:
            x_row = 'E'

        seats_button = tkinter.Button(windowmain, text = '%s' % (str(x_row)+str(y+1)), command = lambda: messagebox.showinfo('Testing',seats_button.cget('text')),font=customFont) # Says E10 as it was the last created widget
        seats_button.grid(row = x, column = y)

        if str(x_row)+str(y+1) in available[0] or str(x_row)+str(y+1) in available[1] or str(x_row)+str(y+1) in available[2] or str(x_row)+str(y+1) in available[3] or str(x_row)+str(y+1) in available[4]:
            seats_button["background"] = 'green'
```

How should I go about fixing this? Thanks!

Full code: https://pastebin.com/awQ50bp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lambda` with a string argument for the button's `command` and set the default value of the string argument to the button text:

```
btnText = '%s' % (str(x_row)+str(y+1))
seats_button = tkinter.Button(windowmain, text = btnText, command = lambda s=btnText: messagebox.showinfo('Testing',s),font=customFont)
```

It is because the default value is constructed when defining the `lambda`.

***Suggestion for changing seat color based on your code:***

Change `btn_list` from local `array` to global `dictionary` using the `btnText` as the key:

```
btn_list = {}   # defined in global area and replaced the line btn_list = [] inside function bookinginterface()
...
btn_list[btnText] = seats_button   # replaced the line btn_list.append(seats_button)
```

Define a new function to be called by the lambda:

```
def seat_selected(seatName):
    messagebox.showinfo('Testing', seatName)
    btn_list[seatName]["background"] = "whatever color you want"
    # do other stuff you want
    ...

...

seats_button = tkinter.Button(windowmain, text=btnText, command=lambda s=btnText: seat_selected(s), font=customFont)
```

Comment: What about the colour of the seat?